# Unidirectional @OneToOne using IDs

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin, jpa

I want to create a `@OneToOne` unidirectional relationship using ID's.
Let's consider following example:

```
@Table(name = "user")
@Entity
class User (

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(...)
    var id: Long? = null,

    @OneToOne
    var address: UserAddress? = null
)

@Table(name = "user_address")
@Entity
class UserAddress(
    @Id
    var id: Long? = null,

    (...)
)
```

On database there is a foreign key constraint on `user_address.id` referencing `user.id`.
I tried using many different annotation combinations, but I still had a problem with deletion. I am using JpaRepository of User and when `userRepository.deleteById(id)` is called, only child (`address`) is deleted, but not a parent (`user`). I would realy like to keep `@Id` columns with name "id". Is it even possible?

**EDIT**

When I use following code:

```
@Table(name = "user")
@Entity
class User (

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(...)
    var id: Long? = null,

    @OneToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.All])
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    var address: UserAddress? = null
)

@Table(name = "user_address")
@Entity
class UserAddress(
    @Id
    var id: Long? = null,


    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "address")
    var user: User? = null
    (...)
)
```

When `userRepository.deleteById(id)` is called, only child is deleted. I have no idea why... In addition I would like to keep this relation unidirectional.

**EDIT** User repository

```
@Repository
interface UserRepository : JpaRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

**EDIT - SOLVED**
Ok. I have another entity (let's call it Company) which has `Set<User>`. It turns out that having it Fetch. EAGER prevents the user from being deleted...
Thank everyone for your time. I had no idea that it might be a problem thus I haven't mentioned it...

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a cascading delete, which you can achieve by passing `orphanRemoval=true` to your `@OneToOne` annotation.

Example:

```
    @OneToOne(orphanRemoval=true)
    var address: UserAddress? = null
```

Alternatively, you could also use `cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE` instead of `orphanremoval=true`.

Borrowed from [ObjectDB](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/delete):

> If `orphanRemoval=true` is specified the disconnected Address instance
>   is automatically removed. This is useful for cleaning up dependent
>   objects (e.g. Address) that should not exist without a reference from
>   an owner object (e.g. Employee). If only `cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE`
>   is specified no automatic action is taken since disconnecting a
>   relationship is not a remove operation.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah.... But what about mapping? Code I wrote does not work in general. I just wanted to show general idea :/

Comment: Ah, I see! I'm sorry, I thought that only the deletion wasn't working. In that case, see Alexandrus answer, he should have it covered pretty much, as I see it.

Answer (score 0):

Various issues.

- The mappings are the wrong way round. `@JoinColumn` needs to be on other side i.e. that with the FK. The way you have defined it at the moment you are effectively saying that Address is dependent on (has a FK to) Address.
- You have redefined the `@Id` field on the dependent entity even though it derives its ID from the `User` entity. You need to remove that and indicate that it is a shared Primary Key relationship here by annotating the relationship with `@Id`.

Given this you will need to make this a bidirectional relationship :

**User:**

```
@Table(name = "user")
@Entity
class User (

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(...)
    var id: Long? = null,

    @OneToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.All], mappedBy="user")
    var address: UserAddress? = null
)
```

**Address:**

```
@Table(name = "user_address")
@Entity
class UserAddress(
    @Id
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    var user: User? = null
    (...)
)
```

Comment: Still, when deleting parent by JpaRepository (`userRepository.deleteById(id)`) parent is not deleted.

Comment: If you are acalling `deleteById` on the UserRepository I really don't see how what you are stating can happen. You will need to  add your repository and any other relevant logic to your question.

Comment: I added it in queston.

Comment: Turn on SQL logging and add SQL statements generated when you delete.

Comment: Delete for User is not called. Only for children (if present). There is no error at all, just User is not deleted.